# how to use gdal command inside php exec() function

Tags: gdal, php

I need to develop a webportal which will display the images generated by a GIS software package. I my development I need to run gdal command inside php `exec()` function. but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Be VERY careful allowing PHP to call system executables (if you can, just don't). Read http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html specifically '#12 Disabling Dangerous PHP Functions.'

Answer (score 6):

it works under PHP 4, PHP 5. beside this you can use **passthru** command too.. passthru command execute an external program and display raw output.

```
exec — Execute an external program
```

Description

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

> exec() executes the given command.

there is an example [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48403). but they are complaining that it works a bit slow.

```
<?php

// gdal_translate converts GIS data
// in this case, simply copy a GeoTIFF with no transforms
$command = 'gdal_translate /tmp/in.tif /tmp/out.tif';

$t0 = microtime(true);
exec($command);
$t1 = microtime(true);

printf("%.1f seconds", $t1 - $t0);
?>
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: @Mehedi - Please mark this as accepted if it indeed solved your problem.