# QGIS SERVER - convert WFS GetFeature GML as Shapefile with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, wfs, ogr, ogr2ogr, qgis-server

I'd like to use ogr2ogr with the [WFS driver](https://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html) to convert the GML response of my QGIS Server 3.4.2 GetFeature layer into Shapefile. I have to do this from a WebGIS JavaScript application I am developing, via (e.g.) a click event on a "Download" button.

First of all, is there a way to do this with QGIS Server itself without implementing this functionality myself (I cannot see any `outputFormat` for Shapefile)?

If this Scenario (let's call it **Scenario 1**) is not possible, I thought about two alternatives, and I'd like to ask which should be the best.

- **Scenario 2**: using PHP exec() like explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26292/how-to-use-gdal-command-inside-php-exec-function/26294#26294)
- **Scenario 3**: using the node.js ogr2ogr wrapper found in [this repo](https://github.com/wavded/ogr2ogr)

Here is the GetCapabilities of my WFS: https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: What kind of filters do you want to use with GetFeatures? Simple bbox ones or something more advanced?

Comment: Well, for now simple bbox will be just fine but ideally I'll make something that will work with advanced filters as well. At present I am building my GetFeature requests with OpenLayers API. Indeed, I didn't think how to pass those to ogr2ogr function to make the conversion.

Comment: Anyway, to clarify let's say I discover a way to intercept the GetFeature requests I make with OL (I am using readFeatures() method from ol/format/WFS to build them dinamically), I would then pass them to ogr2ogr with one of the scenarios I showed to be able to convert the GML3 response to SHP, using the wfs_driver (https://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the service with `ogrinfo`

```
ogrinfo WFS:"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"
```

Result:

```
...
Metadata:
  PROVIDER_NAME=Wondermap
  TITLE=Impianti sciistici Lombardia
1: domini_sciabili (Multi Polygon)
2: impianti_risalita (Multi Line String)
3: piste_sci (Multi Line String)
```

Find summary of one layer

```
ogrinfo WFS:"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" domini_sciabili -so
```

Result

```
Metadata:
  PROVIDER_NAME=Wondermap
  TITLE=Impianti sciistici Lombardia

Layer name: domini_sciabili
Metadata:
  TITLE=domini sciabili
Geometry: Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 38
Extent: (526875.694200, 5096641.169516) - (615063.094113, 5155811.7
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Geometry Column = geometry
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
Id: Integer (0.0)
CODICE: String (0.0)
SOSTENIBIL: String (0.0)
COMUNE: String (0.0)
DENOMINAZ: String (0.0)
FONTE: String (0.0)
STATO: String (0.0)
```

Get features with BBOX and save into shapefile

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -spat 544138 5098446 564138 5108446 wfs_test.shp WFS:"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" domini_sciabili
```

Check what you got

```
ogrinfo wfs_test.shp -so

INFO: Open of `wfs_test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: wfs_test
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2018-12-16
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (543944.462085, 5096641.169516) - (544546.601519, 5098546.684997)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
gml_id: String (80.0)
Id: Integer (9.0)
CODICE: String (80.0)
SOSTENIBIL: String (80.0)
COMUNE: String (80.0)
DENOMINAZ: String (80.0)
FONTE: String (80.0)
STATO: String (80.0)
```

For attribute queries use `ogr2ogr` with `-where` or `-sql` as documented https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. I suggest to read also the WFS driver manual https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Also, really appreciate your examples. Although my question was more about whether to use QGIS SERVER itself (Scenario 1), or ogr2ogr with PHP exec() or nodejs repo (Scenario 2, 3), I think I'll accept it anyway because it gave me good reason to use ogr2ogr. I wonder if I could combine OpenLayers [writeGetFeature()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WFS-WFS.html#writeGetFeature) with ogr2ogr, but this is another story... Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if I can use the `bbox` optional parameter of the WFS standard directly in the WFS URL instead of the `-spat` ogr option? Something like `https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=domini_sciabili&bbox=544138,5098446,564138,5108446`

Comment: Just tested: yes it does! Wonderful!!! Tried with `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp WFS:"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=domini_sciabili&bbox=544138,5098446,564138,5108446"`

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, is there a way to do this with QGIS Server itself

There's a QGIS-Server plugin `wfsOutputExtension` which adds a lot of output formats, among them `ESRI ShapeFile as ZIP file`:

https://github.com/3liz/qgis-wfsOutputExtension

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this might be to use GeoServer as an intermediary to proxy the remote WFS and then just request SHAPE-ZIP as the output format of the GeoServer WFS request.

Comment: @IanTutrton Thanks for the feedback, but I'd like to avoid installing and configuring such a component only to convert formats. If there's no real reason not to, I'd like to possibly stick with one of the scenarios I've mentioned. Of course I am open to altenatives, but yours seems a bit too much for me, as I don't really know Geoserver. Thank you for the suggestion though, I really appreciate your help.